# One-Server vs Multi Clients Realtime monitoring System using - Indy components(idTCPServer/idTCPClient) in DELPHI

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy, indy10, server-push

I have a important problem with building Indy Server/Clients realtime monitoring system...
I am using DELPHI 2010, and Indy version is 10.5.5.........
My purpose is that many client side PCs send screenshots continuosely(4~10fps) to Server, and Server have to send these screenshots frames to some monitoring PCs.
In other words....

```
Many clients -----send streams--------> to Server
Some monitors <---receive streams----- from Server
```

Of course, In the case of one client and one monitor with server works well...
But if connecting another clients or monitors, then server have been raising exceptions "Access violation at address 000000000.....", or "Invalid pointer operations" and disconnects client's connection or monitor's one.

At the result, client or monitor will be disconnected from server....

I have used idTCPClient component, described client and monitor code using thread for sending and receiving stream.
I am sure there is no problem with client and monitor side's Code...
But I think that there will be absolutely problem with server side.

For server side, I have used two TidTCPServer controls...
One is to receive streams from client PCs.And another is to send streams to monitor PCs.

server code is like below...

```
{one side----idTCPServerRecv is to receive screenshot streams from clients}

procedure TIndyServerForm.IdTCPServer_RecvExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Hb: TIdIOHandler;
  TempStr: TStrings;
begin

  Hb := AContext.Connection.IOHandler;
  if Not Hb.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  Begin
    Hb.CheckForDisconnect(True, True);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect(True, True);

    recv_Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    recv_Stream.Clear;
    if (ReceiveStream(AContext, TStream(recv_Stream)) = False) then
    begin
      ROutMsg :=AContext.Binding.PeerIP+' -> receiving failed: ' + IntToStr(recv_Stream.Size)+'byte';
      recv_Stream.Free;
      Exit;
    end;
    if recv_Stream.Size < 1024 then
    begin
      recv_Stream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

      ROutMsg :=AContext.Binding.PeerIP+' -> captionString received('+
                IntToStr(recv_Stream.Size)+' byte) : "'+StringFromStream(TStream(recv_Stream))+'"';
      recv_Stream.Free;

    end
    else
    begin
      ROutMsg :=AContext.Binding.PeerIP+' -> screenshot received: ' + KBStr(recv_Stream.Size)+' KB';
      if G_Sendable = False then
      begin
        send_Stream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
        send_Stream.Clear;
        recv_Stream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
        send_Stream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
        send_Stream.CopyFrom(recv_Stream, recv_Stream.Size);
        G_Sendable :=True;
      end;
      recv_Stream.Free;

    end;
  end;
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  WaitForSingleObject(Handle, 1);
end;


{another side----idTCPServerSend is to send screenshot streams to monitors}

procedure TIndyServerForm.IdTCPServer_SendExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
    if G_Sendable then
    begin
      send_Stream.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
      if (SendStream(AContext, TStream(send_Stream)) = False) then
      begin
        SOutMsg :=AContext.Binding.PeerIP+' -> sending failed -> ' + KBStr(send_Stream.Size)+' KB';
        send_Stream.Free;
        G_Sendable :=False;
        Exit;
      end;
      SOutMsg :=AContext.Binding.PeerIP+' -> sending successful-> ' + KBStr(send_Stream.Size)+' KB';
      send_Stream.Free;
      G_Sendable :=False;
    end;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    WaitForSingleObject(Handle, 1);


end;
```

What should I do for multi-clients connections with realtime exchange of streams...
Every client PC send screenshot stream 4~10 times per second...
And these streams must be sent to monitors corresponding
Please give me advice....

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not even close to being thread-safe, which is why you are having errors. Every client thread in `IdTCPServer_Recv` is receiving their respective screeshots to a single shared `recv_Stream` variable, and then copying that data to a single shared `send_Stream` variable. All clients connected to `IdTCPServer_Send` are then reading and sending the same `send_Stream` at the same time. You are trampling memory all over the place.

You need to use a local variable instead of a shared variable to receive each screenshot, and you need to use a *separate* `TStream` object for each monitor client.  Don't use a shared `TStream` for sending, and certainly don't use a global boolean variable to let each monitor client go at it. Have `IdTCPServer_RecvExecute()` actively create and pass along a new `TMemoryStream` object to each monitor client that needs to send the current screenshot.

Try something more like this:

```
uses
  ..., IdThreadSafe;

type
  TMonitorContext = class(TIdServerContext)
  public
    Screenshots: TIdThreadSafeObjectList;
    ScreenshotEvent: THandle;
    constructor Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TThreadList = nil); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TScreenshotInfo = class
  public
    ClientIP: string;
    ClientPort: TIdPort;
    Data: TMemoryStream;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMonitorContext.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TThreadList);
begin
  inherited;
  Screenshots := TIdThreadSafeObjectList.Create;
  Screenshots.OwnsObjects := True;
  ScreenshotEvent := CreateEvent(null, True, False, nil);
end;

destructor TMonitorContext.Destroy;
begin
  Screenshots.Free;
  CloseHandle(ScreenshotEvent);
  inherited;
end;

constructor TScreenshotInfo.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  Data := TMemoryStream.Create;
end;

destructor TScreenshotInfo.Destroy;
begin
  Data.Free;
  inherited;
end;

{one side----idTCPServerRecv is to receive screenshot streams from clients}

procedure TIndyServerForm.IdTCPServer_RecvExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  recv_stream: TMemoryStream;
  monitors, queue: TList;
  i: Integer;
  screenshot: TScreenshotInfo;
  monitor: TMonitorContext;
begin
  recv_stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    if not ReceiveStream(AContext, recv_stream) then
    begin
      ROutMsg := AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ' -> receiving failed: ' + IntToStr(recv_Stream.Size) + ' byte';
      Exit;
    end;
    if recv_Stream.Size < 1024 then
    begin
      recv_Stream.Position := 0;
      ROutMsg := AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ' -> captionString received(' + 
                IntToStr(recv_Stream.Size) + ' byte) : "' + StringFromStream(recv_Stream) + '"';
    end
    else
    begin
      ROutMsg := AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ' -> screenshot received: ' + KBStr(recv_Stream.Size) + ' KB';

      monitors := IdTCPServer_Send.Contexts.LockList;
      try
        // alternatively, only queue the screenshot to particular monitors
        // that are actually interested in this client...
        for i := 0 to monitors.Count-1 do
        begin
          monitor := TMonitorContext(monitors[i]);
          screenshot := TScreenshotInfo.Create;
          try
            recv_Stream.Position := 0;
            screenshot.Data.CopyFrom(recv_stream, 0);
            screenshot.Data.Position := 0;
            queue := monitor.Screenshots.LockList;
            try
              queue.Add(screenshot);
              SetEvent(monitor.ScreenshotEvent);
            finally
              monitor.Screenshots.UnlockList;
            end;
          except
            screenshot.Free;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        IdTCPServer_Send.Contexts.UnlockList;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    recv_stream.Free;
  end;
end;

{another side----idTCPServerSend is to send screenshot streams to monitors}

procedure TIndyServerForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer_Send.ContextClass := TMonitorContext;
end;

procedure TIndyServerForm.IdTCPServer_SendExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  monitor: TMonitorContext;
  queue: TList;
  i: Integer;
  screenshot: TScreenshotInfo;
begin
  monitor := TMonitorContext(AContext);
  if WaitForSingleObject(monitor.ScreenshotEvent, 1000) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then Exit;
  screenshot := nil;
  try
    queue := monitor.Screenshots.LockList;
    try
      if queue.Count > 0 then
      begin
        screenshot := TScreenshotInfo(queue[0]);
        queue.Delete(0);
      end;
      if queue.Count = 0 then
        ResetEvent(monitor.ScreenshotEvent);
    finally
      monitor.Screenshots.UnlockList;
    end;
    if screenshot = nil then Exit;
    // you should send screenshot.ClientIP and screenshot.ClientPort to
    // this monitor so it knows which client the screenshot came from...
    if not SendStream(AContext, screenshot.Data) then
    begin
      SOutMsg := AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ' -> sending failed -> ' + KBStr(screenshot.Data.Size) + ' KB';
      Exit;
    end;
    SOutMsg := AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ' -> sending successful-> ' + KBStr(screenshot.Data.Size) + ' KB';
  finally
    screenshot.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You really give me importandt advice and help. In fact after posting I have found a problem related thread safe.....

Comment: Hi, Sir ! I have tried by your modification code,, but your code doesn't work in my DELPHI and INDY environment. For eg......TIdThreadSafeObjectList, TIdContextThreadList are not existed...How should I do???

Comment: TIdContextThreadList was added in a later version. Replace it with TThreadList. TIdThreadSafeObjectList is in the IdThreadSafe unit.

Answer (score 1):

On the 'monitor' side, a TIdTCPClient in a thread can listen for incoming screenshot data from the server. I have posted a blog article about server-side push messaging technique with Indy (source code) here:

[Indy 10 TIdTCPServer: Server-side message push example](https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/indy-10-tidtcpserver-server-side-message-push-example/)

Additional server-side code is required to direct the incoming data to the monitoring clients. Actually you only need to add 'tags' (which could be boolean flags) to the context, indicating wether this connection is sending or monitoring screenshot data. How to assign custom properties to connection context and iterating over them is already answered in other questions here on SO.

Comment: Thanks you for your advice. But what I want know is to why occuring exception on server Side....